# How to merge two user tables and associated usermeta tables

Tags: mysql, merge

I have 2 similar databases both having user and usermeta tables. I need to merge these tables. 
So there are 2 user tables like these
[image]

and 2 usermeta tables like these
[image]

from which I want to generate the merged user and usermeta tables
[image]

I am able to merge the user tables (obviously!) by just inserting the values from user table 2 (without IDs) to user table 1, giving me me the new user table 1 and the lookup between old and new IDs of the added users

[image][image]

What is a good way of now replacing the old user_id values in usermeta 2 table data, so that i can insert them in the usermeta 1 table to merge it i.e. I want to get this from usermeta 2
[image]

I can do it in Excel/CSV through vlookup, but sometimes converting data from SQL to Excel/CSV and back is tricky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `JOIN` the tables `usermeta2` and `id_lookup` and update `user_id` with `new_id`

```
UPDATE usermeta2 um2 JOIN id_lookup idl ON um2.user_id = idl.old_id
SET um2.user_id = idl.new_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the autoincrement feature to get the new id (by inserting the data without id), you HAVE TO add a column with the old primary key to your new user table (which you can drop after your merge is done). The primary key identifies a row, and if you remove it, you will not be able to link your old and your new ids anymore. So use e.g.

```
insert into newuser (id, email, ..., old_id)
select null, email, ... , id
from user2
```

Your lookup table is now automatically available, and will simply be `select id, old_id from newuser`. Since you want to let MySQL decide on the new (autoincrement) id during the merge, you obviously cannot generate a lookup table before the merge.

Using this information, to insert the meta values from your second database, you can then use e.g.

```
insert into newusermeta (id, user_id, ..., old_id)
select null, lookup.id, ... usermeta2.id
from usermeta2
left join (select id, old_id from newuser) as lookup
on lookup.old_id = usermeta2.id
```

Your meta-lookuptable in the form you had it in your question will similarly be

```
select newmeta.id, newmeta.user_id, newmeta.old_id, newuser.old_id 
from newmeta 
left join newuser on newmeta.user_id = newuser.id
```

although you actually don't need the 2 *userids* there. Since everywhere you have to replace a *metaid*, it would be just the *metaid* without the *userid*, and so `select id, old_id from newmeta` should suffice.

The `left join` is used only in case you have corrupt data (e.g. meta data without users). If you are sure all parents exist, you can use a normal `join` (but it will then silently ignore any metadata without parents).

Things can get a lot more complicated that this though. Consider e.g. duplicates. You might have a unique index on `email` to prevent duplicates. If you have a user with that email in both tables, you cannot simply merge them by getting a new primary key anymore, because it will still violate the unique constraint. But you cannot simply ignore one either, as they can be different users (e.g. friends or family sharing an email) or have different details (e.g. order history or a different address because they moved). It's up to you to handle such situations and prepare your data. There is no general receipt for solving this, and actually there is a whole industry that specializes in just cleaning up such data.

An alternative to getting new ids via autoincrement would e.g. be to add a fixed value per key (which you have to define once or calculate on the fly) when you insert them, e.g. add `+2` to everywhere you are using the *userid*, and `+4` everywhere you are using the *metaid*, e.g.

```
insert into newusermeta (id, user_id, ...)
select id, user_id, ... from usermeta1
union select id+4, user_id+2, ... from usermeta2
```

Here you could generate the lookup tables before the merge (since you instead of MySQL define the new keys), although they wouldn't serve much purpose, since you just add a fixed number.

Or you can update the data in (a copy of) database 2 before you merge it. Add `on update cascade` to every foreign key you are using (or now creating). Then simply update the primary keys, e.g.

```
update user2 set id = id + 2 order by id desc;
update usermeta2 set id = id + 4 order by id desc;
```

and it will update the `user_id` in the metatable on its own. This has the advantage that the database will be consistent before you merge it. It will not work for *MyISAM*-tables though, as they don't support foreign keys.